# After Effects: Mac to PC

Tags: macos, conversion, compatibility, adobe-after-effects

Is it possible to open an After Effects file that's been created on a Mac with PC? I don't know what version the AE was on the Mac side, but I want to oepn it with CS3 on a PC laptop.

Comment: did you just try?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Perhaps the problem is to do with new/old versions, as red-X suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is created with a newer version of after effects it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunatelly, I have no way of finding out what version the Mac one was. =(

Answer (score 0):

You can open with PC. This is very sample but You must have project data. I used video1.avi, video2.avi and audio.wav. So, you must have this project data in your package. If you used some aftereffect plugin on mac, you must need this plugin for windows.